# Changing hardware after total system clone?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, clone

I bought a new SSD and would love to clone everything from my HDD onto it, but in multiple places online I have seen that if I do that, then it will only work on the current/same chipset. My concern is that if/when I upgrade my computer (to a newer/better chipset), that I will be unable to use it without repurchasing Windows 10. I've also seen some sources say that Windows is tied to the computer itself, which I am not sure how a mobo swap would affect this.

Is there any substance to the claim of Windows breaking in another chipset after a clone and if so is there a way to work around it?

P.S. if there is a different/better way to move the system over to an SSD, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your SSD should not cause any issues, but if you upgrade your motherboard you will most likely loose your license (if its an OEM one).   If you do upgrade your computer in such a way as to void your license you would be able to purchase a new license and activate it.  This is painful on the pocket but not particularly hard.

A bigger problem is that Windows is picky about the drivers it has, and changing out a motherboard or other key components for one with a different different chipsets can cause Windows to not work, and fixing this is not trivial - indeed a reinstall is usually the best way.   I'm a bit out of touch with this side of things but I recall people abusing the "[sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation)"  function to generalise their install and migrate it to another system.  IIRC this is using it from outside its design scope, but often works.  (I believe sysprep was designed to make a customised image that can be deployed to multiple systems)

Comment: I changed my mobo and CPU a few months ago with no issues (B250 chipset to B365), is that an outlier then? And if I do have to purchase a new license, does that effect any of the data stored on the computer or is it basically just unlocking it from Windows' version of ransomeware?